# SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 2

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, spring-boot, post

I'm working on React and hitting a POST API made using spring Boot.
here's code

```
async postData() {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state));
  try {
    const results = await fetch("/student", {
      crossDomain: true,
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state),
    });

    const data = await results.json();
    console.log("data", data);
    //this.props.history.push("/Resume");

    this.setState({
      owner: "",
      student_field_interest1: "",
      student_field_interest2: "",
      firstname: "",
      lastname: "",
      contactno: 0,
      address: "",
      gender: "",
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

before hitting the API 
I'm sending this JSON object

```
{"data":[],"owner":"5eeaac70f21e4c2b3a35a8c0","student_field_interest1":"ML","student_field_interest2":"DL","firstname":"Pushkar","lastname":"Jain","contactno":"09991736000","address":"Room no 106 Oxford Caps Upes Road","gender":"Male"}
```

and on hitting 
I'm getting this error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 2

Comment: What is the server returning?  Sounds like it's not valid JSON.

Comment: Can you post the output of console.log?

Comment: It could be a server side error, can you check the springboot console if there is an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the API response?, I try in a local environment and works fine
[image: Result Example] the result message is an error but was intentional thas was the result expected.

Answer (score -2):

Your this.state doesn't have a valid json. PLease validate your JSON from the following url
https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

Post is not going to work with the invalid json